# GDP in expenditure approach

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp

GDP calculated using expenditure apporach is like this:
GDP=C+I+G+(X-M)
However on this site:
http://www.singstat.gov.sg/statistics/visualising-data/charts/share-of-gdp-by-expenditure

The data is avaialable for C, G and net exports, but there are two variables: Gross Fixed Capital Formation and Changes In Inventories. Since there is no 'I' variable, can I assume that the sum of those two variables are equal I?

Comment: What's stopping you from doing so? Why do you think that it is or it isn't part of I?

Comment: Given that all other variables are the same then i suppose that those two might equal I, however im not sure thats why I ask

Comment: Those are certainly components of investment. I am unsure whether there is something missing. If all the numbers shown add up to 100%, then you seem to be right. You would need to get a guide from the statistical agency to get a more authoritative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authoritative source here is the [United Nations System of National Accounts](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/nationalaccount/sna.asp), SNA.

Change in inventories are indeed part of what we normally call Investment. First, for clarification, the definition of "change in inventories", taken from page 108 of [SNA, version 2008](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/nationalaccount/docs/SNA2008.pdf):

> The basic principle underlying the measurement of changes
>   in  inventories  of  finished  goods  is  that  **output  should  be
>   recorded at the time it is produced** and valued at the same
>   price  **whether  it  is  sold,  otherwise  used  or  entered  into
>   inventories for sale or use later**. In effect, goods only enter
>   inventories when they are not immediately used
>    for sale or other use in the period they
>    are produced. Similarly, goods are  withdrawn  from  inventories  when  the  demand  for  the
>   goods exceeds the amount produced in a period. **No output
>   is recorded when goods produced previously are withdrawn
>   from  inventories  and  sold**  or  otherwise  used  unless  a
>   storage activity as described be low in section F takes place.

Second, the components of "Investment" (officially called Gross capital formation), as stated in page 282 of the aforementioned document is:

> There are three types of capital formation to be examined,
>   gross  fixed  capital  formation,
>     changes  in  inventories  and
>   acquisition less disposal of valuables.

This and following pages go about explaining each of them, and how to measure them.

Finally, the document provides a worked example of the table of "uses of output" (the expenditure approach of GDP). Here is a screenshot of a section of that worked example, presented in page 291. You can see that change in inventories are indeed treated as part of "Gross Capital Formation":

[image]